# Can someone explain weird behavior in Php?

Tags: php, syntax

This is not possible in Python:

```
Python 2.7.3
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
>>> b = 15
>>> a = 15 + b = 16
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
>>>
```

I can test the same in C, C++, Java and JavaScript...

```
var b=15 ; var a = 15+ b = 15
VM155:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment(…)
```

But can someone explain me why this works in Php, and why?

```
php -r '$b = 15; $a = "45". $b = 15;'
```

Comment: That's very interesting. Concatenation has higher precedence than assignment. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: It works because it's valid PHP syntax. If you're looking for reason why it's valid, you can pose the same question for languages you referred to - how come it *isn't* valid there?

Comment: It isn't valid with all other languages because it's damn *logical*. *Obvious*. *Flawless*. Everything but what Php is.

Comment: I don't know why you have the need to attack me for problems that you have, but there is no logical conclusion here. It's arbitrary and the decision lies upon the language designers - your starting points are wrong. If you don't like it, don't use the language, you're apparently versed in other languages. Barking at me or the language won't return the time and fix the mistake you created when you performed the typo which caused you to lose the time. There exists no language that can prevent silly mistakes or read people's minds, neither C and definitely not PHP.

Comment: Assignments are expressions in a lot of languages: C, C++, C#, Javascript, PHP, Java, Ruby, etc. In e.g. Python assignments are statements, which is why it does not work there. In any case, you should avoid assigning inside expressions (except for in constructs where it is normal, like `for` and `while`).

Comment: PHP is a scripting language, so by nature it is permissive & weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an assignment happens, PHP [returns the value that was assigned](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php).

So if you were to do `echo $a = 3;` you would get `3` in the PHP out.

Another example from the same docs linked above:

```
$a = ($b = 4) + 5; // $a is equal to 9 now, and $b has been set to 4.
```

Simply put, it's desired behaviour in the context of the language and its documentation. Python doesn't adopt this behaviour.

Interestingly, I *can* also do this with other quite powerful programming languages. Here's Ruby:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-14:/vagrant$ irb
2.1.2 :001 > a = (b = 4) + 5
 => 9 
2.1.2 :002 > b
 => 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You may say that is an unfortunate feature that can induce you to an error, but nothing is wrong with syntax.
PHP evaluates this as an assignment expression. When you say `$a = 'some string' . $b = $c` you are concatenating `'some string'` to php evaluation result for `$b = $c`.